# Training with pre-trained weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to use a set of pre-trained weights to train my model for MNIST classification. More specifically, I train my model on one dataset. I want to use the final weights as the starting weights to train the model on a different dataset. To do this, I use

```py
intial_weights = model1.get_weights()
model2 = create_model()
model2.set_weights(initial_weights)
model2.fit(x=x_train59,y=y_train59, epochs=20,callbacks = [cp_callback2])
```

My question is that whether model.fit() will ignore the initial weights set using model2.set_weights() or not. And if it does ignore, is there a way to make sure that model2.fit() uses the weights obtained previously. Also, is there a way to visualize the starting weights before model.fit() starts training. Thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

When you do `model2.set_weights`, you changed the weights of `model2`. That's all.

You can see the weights the same way: `w2 = model2.get_weights()`. Then print `w2` in a convenient way.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I understand that I change the weights of model2. But when I do model2.fit() after that, does the fit() function re-initialize the weights to random weights or it starts from the weights set before. I apologize if I miss something.

Comment: No, nothing reinitializes the weights of a model. They're initialized only once when you create the model.

Comment: Ok, thanks! So from your answer I understand that

model2 = create_model();

model2.set_weights(my_weights);

model2.fit();

would run the training on model2 starting with my_weights. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Yes. `create_model()` attributes random permanent weights to the model. `set_weights()` changes the permanent weights to your desired values. `fit()` starts from the current weights.